# WPF select combobox item after listbox item being click

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

I would like to select the listbox item, then the comboxbox item will being selected. below is my code, please check, Thank you for help.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetValues"
                ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}"
                x:Key="GenderDataProvider">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="d:GenderEnum" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>

        <ListBox Name="lbUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentUser}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />

            <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GenderDataProvider}}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentUser.Gender}" />

            <TextBox Name="txtUserName" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Width="200" Text="{Binding Path=CurrentUser.Name}" />

    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the below lines of code in your code and let me know the result.

ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GenderDataProvider}}" SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentUser, Path=Gender}" />

TextBox Name="txtUserName" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Width="200" Text="{Binding CurrentUser, Path=Name}" />

If this solution didnt provide you the expected result, please explain your requirement in detail.

Comment: hi this is my current error

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Male' property not found on 'object' ''GenderEnum' (HashCode=0)'. BindingExpression:Path=Male; DataItem='GenderEnum' (HashCode=0); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')